# Truth table with actions

Tags: java, design-patterns

In my code I'm evaluating 3 booleans.
Each combination of those booleans truth value requires different action (for example, different method should be executed).
Currently I'm using if-else block (8 options, not that nice).
I'm wondering if there's another option to write this code which will make it 'prettier'.
Maybe design pattern?
Someone has an idea?

Comment: You can combine the three booleans into an integer in the range  of 0-7 and use a switch statement.

Comment: can you share the code.. what you have tried so far?

Comment: In any possibility, u should give the priority of the conditions so u should give the code the sequence of the checks. U should write if's or switch/case or something similar to that logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use  [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

```
public interface Command {
     void exec();
}

public class CommandA() implements Command {

     void exec() {
          // ... 
     }
}
```

Build a Map object and populate it with Command instances:

Then you can do something like this in your by iterating over the map.

```
commandMap.get(value).exec();
```

Answer (score 4):

use a switch block

```
switch ((A?4:0) + (B?2:0) + (C?1:0)){
case  0: //A,B,C false 
break;

case  3: //A False, B,C true
break;

case  4: //A True, B,C false 
break;
}
```

Comment: Or you can save the Bolean values in bitmask like this:
100,
010,
011,
...
and then use switch on this variable straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Three elements is not too bad, but what if your table contained 4 or 5 or 25? Can get complicated.
Here is a compact technique some will find usfull while others will shoot down.

Build a string of the table elements:

```
final boolean a = false, b = false, c = false;
final String method = "state"+(a?"AT":"AF")+(b?"BT":"BF")+(c?"CT":"CF");
```

This produces strings like:

```
// stateAFBFCF
// stateAFBTCF
// stateAFBFCT
...
```

Create methods by the same names to handle each combo of states:

```
public void stateAFBTCF() { }
public void stateAFBTCF() { }
public void stateAFBFCT() { }
...
```

Use reflection to call the correct method:

```
final Class<?> _class = handler.getClass();
final Method _method = _class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, new Class[] {});
_method.invoke(handler, new Object[] { });
```

Comment: good idea, only downside is that the check for method existence is done at run-time.

Comment: @LefterisE - Agree, although some might prefer the runtime exception as opposed to coding all the conditional checkers.  A try/catch at getDeclaredMethod() can make it less of a slap in the face.

Answer (score 0):

If you whatever have as many methods as possible combinations, you could check the combinations at the entrance of the different methods:

```java
public void a(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
    if (a && !b && !c) {
    }
}

public void ab(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
    if (a && b && !c) {
    }
}

public void abc(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
    if (a && b && c) {
    }
}

public void ac(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
    if (a && !b && c) {
    }
}

public void b(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
    if (!a && b && !c) {
    }
}

public void bc(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
    if (!a && b && c) {
    }
}

public void c(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
    if (!a && !b && c) {
    }
}

public void none(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
    if (!a && !b && !c) {
    }
}
```

Then, simply call all of them:

```java
a(a, b, c);
ab(a, b, c);
abc(a, b, c);
ac(a, b, c);
b(a, b, c);
bc(a, b, c);
c(a, b, c);
none(a, b, c);
```